# How can I get the value of a given column for the selected row in a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

Knowing the name of the column to be queried, how can I extract the value from that column for the currently selected record in a DataGridView?

IOW, if I have a DataGridView with columns named id, Date, Time, Space, and I want the value of the Space column for the currently selected row, how can I assign that value to a String variable?

In pseudocode, I would expect it to be something like:

```
String s = dataGridView1.CurrentRow["Space"].ToString();
```

...but I'm sure it's not really that straightforward.

### UPDATE

The answers look good, but is there a way to get the value from the current row that doesn't respond to a dataGridView event? I need to assign the value apart from the dataGridView being clicked or any other event. IOW: is there a way to get the current row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[yourColumn]
```

to access the current row if there is one..
..and even if you have MultiSelect on, you can always use

```
dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[yourColumn]
```

to access the first selected row..

Comment: Cool; this is a more straightforward way than my step-by-step idea; simply "String colVal = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[colName];

Comment: Yes. Please check on the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentrow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) docs; you'll see a) how to set the currentrow and b) that there may not be a row 'current'!

Answer (score 1):

In the  `Grid_RowDataBound` event

```
    protected void Grid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.DataItem == null)
            return;

        DataRowView row = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

        if(row["Space"] != null)
        {
            string s = row["Space"].ToString();
            //do stuff
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value != null)
    {
       string s = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Space"].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I reckon this will work:

```
private string GetCurrentOrFirstValOfColumn(string colName)
{
    String colVal = String.Empty;
    DataGridViewRow dgvr = dataGridViewFileContents.CurrentRow;
    if (null != dgvr.Cells[colName].Value)
    {
        colVal = dgvr.Cells[colName].Value.ToString();
    }
    return colVal;
}
```